# Multiple antMatcher in the Spring Security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I need to configure Spring Security to have multiple filters depending on the path:

- For the path `/admin/**` I need to use `.addFilter(getAdminAuthFilter())`
- For the path `/api/**` I need to use `.addFilter(getApiAuthFilter())`

If I write two `antMatcher` the first one seems to be overridden and my configuration doesn't work.

```java
http.csrf().disable()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .antMatcher("/admin/**")
    .addFilter(getAdminAuthFilter())
    .authorizeRequests()//.anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .antMatcher("/api/**")
    .addFilter(getApiAuthFilter())
    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Is it possible to configure the filter depending on the request path?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
http
  // ...
  .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
  .and()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
   .and()
        .antMatcher("/admin/**")
        .addFilterBefore(getAdminAuthFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
        .antMatcher("/api/**")
        .addFilterBefore(getApiAuthFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
   // ...
```

Comment: I've tried something like this. The problem seems that when I add the second `antMatcher` it overrides the first one and whole chain is used only for `/api/**` path